# filter array recursively looking for parents

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, filter, lodash

I have an array like that:

```
[
    {"id":"one","name":"school", "selected": false, "children":[
      {"id":"1","name":"school", "selected": false},
      {"id":"2","name":"student", "selected": true},
      {"id":"3","name":"teacher", "selected": false}
      ]},
      {"name":"two","name":"school", "selected": false, "children":[
      {"id":"1","name":"school", "selected": true},
      {"id":"3","name":"teacher", "selected": false}
      ]},
      {"name":"three","name":"school", "selected": true, "children":[
      {"id":"1","name":"school", "selected": false},
      {"id":"2","name":"student", "selected": false}
      ]}
  ]
```

How I can filter on that array to get only the name of the object that has the field select as true?

The output should be an array for the name of objects:

```
[student, school, school]
```

I tried this using lodash:

```
_.filter(array, {selected: true}).map(function (division) {
            return array.name;
        });
```

But this always return the root objects, never the objects that are inside the children.

Comment: You could use a basic for loop

Comment: Just a note: **children** is the plural of child.

Comment: @sabithpocker Or chilrens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just iterate and look if the wanted property `selected` is `true`, the push to result, if there is a children, iterate the children.

This works with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
var data = [{ "id": "one", "name": "school", "selected": false, "children": [{ "id": "1", "name": "school", "selected": false }, { "id": "2", "name": "student", "selected": true }, { "id": "3", "name": "teacher", "selected": false }] }, { "name": "two", "name": "school", "selected": false, "children": [{ "id": "1", "name": "school", "selected": true }, { "id": "3", "name": "teacher", "selected": false }] }, { "name": "three", "name": "school", "selected": true, "children": [{ "id": "1", "name": "school", "selected": false }, { "id": "2", "name": "student", "selected": false }] }],
    result = [];

data.forEach(function iter(o) {
    o.selected && result.push(o.name);
    (o.children || []).forEach(iter);
});
  
console.log(result);
```

The same with lodash [`_.forEach`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#forEach)

```js
var data = [{ "id": "one", "name": "school", "selected": false, "children": [{ "id": "1", "name": "school", "selected": false }, { "id": "2", "name": "student", "selected": true }, { "id": "3", "name": "teacher", "selected": false }] }, { "name": "two", "name": "school", "selected": false, "children": [{ "id": "1", "name": "school", "selected": true }, { "id": "3", "name": "teacher", "selected": false }] }, { "name": "three", "name": "school", "selected": true, "children": [{ "id": "1", "name": "school", "selected": false }, { "id": "2", "name": "student", "selected": false }] }],
    result = [];

_.forEach(data, function iter(o) {
    o.selected && result.push(o.name);
    _.forEach(o.children, iter);
});
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

A version with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
var data = [{ "id": "one", "name": "school", "selected": false, "children": [{ "id": "1", "name": "school", "selected": false }, { "id": "2", "name": "student", "selected": true }, { "id": "3", "name": "teacher", "selected": false }] }, { "name": "two", "name": "school", "selected": false, "children": [{ "id": "1", "name": "school", "selected": true }, { "id": "3", "name": "teacher", "selected": false }] }, { "name": "three", "name": "school", "selected": true, "children": [{ "id": "1", "name": "school", "selected": false }, { "id": "2", "name": "student", "selected": false }] }],
    result = data.reduce(function iter(r, o) {
        o.selected && r.push(o.name);
        return (o.children || []).reduce(iter, r);
    }, []);
  
console.log(result);
```

And another version with lodash [`_.reduce`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#reduce).

```js
var data = [{ "id": "one", "name": "school", "selected": false, "children": [{ "id": "1", "name": "school", "selected": false }, { "id": "2", "name": "student", "selected": true }, { "id": "3", "name": "teacher", "selected": false }] }, { "name": "two", "name": "school", "selected": false, "children": [{ "id": "1", "name": "school", "selected": true }, { "id": "3", "name": "teacher", "selected": false }] }, { "name": "three", "name": "school", "selected": true, "children": [{ "id": "1", "name": "school", "selected": false }, { "id": "2", "name": "student", "selected": false }] }],
    result = _.reduce(data, function iter(r, o) {
        o.selected && r.push(o.name);
        return _.reduce(o.children, iter, r);
    }, []);
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Let me try that

Answer (score 2):

```
array
   .reduce((a, i) => [...a, i, ...i.childs], [])//flatten array
   .filter(i => i.selected)//filter with selected===true
   .map(i => i.name));//map to name
```

```js
console.log([{
  "id": "one",
  "name": "school",
  "selected": false,
  "childs": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "school",
    "selected": false
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "student",
    "selected": true
  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "teacher",
    "selected": false
  }]
}, {
  "name": "two",
  "name": "school",
  "selected": false,
  "childs": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "school",
    "selected": true
  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "teacher",
    "selected": false
  }]
}, {
  "name": "three",
  "name": "school",
  "selected": true,
  "childs": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "school",
    "selected": false
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "student",
    "selected": false
  }]
}].reduce((a, i) => [...a, i, ...i.childs], []).filter(i => i.selected).map(i => i.name));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this *functional programming* style ES6 solution:

```
function sel(array) {
    return (array || []).reduce ( (acc, o) => 
        (o.selected ? acc.concat(o.name) : acc).concat(sel(o.childs)), [] );
}
```

```js
  
function sel(array) {
    return (array || []).reduce ( (acc, o) => 
        (o.selected ? acc.concat(o.name) : acc).concat(sel(o.childs)), [] );
}
// Sample data
var array = [
    {"id":"one","name":"school", "selected": false, "childs":[
      {"id":"1","name":"school", "selected": false},
      {"id":"2","name":"student", "selected": true},
      {"id":"3","name":"teacher", "selected": false}
      ]},
      {"name":"two","name":"school", "selected": false, "childs":[
      {"id":"1","name":"school", "selected": true},
      {"id":"3","name":"teacher", "selected": false}
      ]},
      {"name":"three","name":"school", "selected": true, "childs":[
      {"id":"1","name":"school", "selected": false},
      {"id":"2","name":"student", "selected": false}
      ]}
  ];
// Extract
var result = sel(array);
// Ooutput result
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.map()`, `Array.prototype.filter()`

```js
var arr = [{
  "id": "one",
  "name": "school",
  "selected": false,
  "childs": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "school",
    "selected": false
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "student",
    "selected": true
  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "teacher",
    "selected": false
  }]
}, {
  "name": "two",
  "name": "school",
  "selected": false,
  "childs": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "school",
    "selected": true
  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "teacher",
    "selected": false
  }]
}, {
  "name": "three",
  "name": "school",
  "selected": true,
  "childs": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "school",
    "selected": false
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "student",
    "selected": false
  }]
}];

var res = arr.map(el =>
  (el.selected && el || el.childs.filter(child =>
    child.selected
  )[0]).name
);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it was great

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should consider the complexity of the script you are trying to build. This is a nested linear algorithm (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search) since you have to touch every single element in the array to create the new data structure with the `selected` elements, which can be very slow if that array size increases.

What you might want to do instead, is to modify the method that toggles the `selected` property, and copy that 'selected' object to a new `selectedElements` array.

However, if you are required to do what you asked, and you only want UNIQUE results, check this out:

```js
var data = [
  {"id":"one","name":"school", "selected": false, "childs":[
    {"id":"1","name":"school", "selected": false},
    {"id":"2","name":"student", "selected": true},
    {"id":"3","name":"teacher", "selected": false}
  ]},
  {"name":"two","name":"school", "selected": false, "childs":[
    {"id":"1","name":"school", "selected": true},
    {"id":"3","name":"teacher", "selected": false}
  ]},
  {"name":"three","name":"school", "selected": true, "childs":[
    {"id":"1","name":"school", "selected": false},
    {"id":"2","name":"student", "selected": false}
  ]}
],
    selectedElements = [];

data.map(function(row, i){
  if (row.selected) {
    if (selectedElements.indexOf(row.name) == - 1)
      selectedElements.push(row.name);
  }
  else{
    row.childs.map(function(childRow, ii) {
      if (childRow.selected) {
        if (selectedElements.indexOf(childRow.name) == - 1)
          selectedElements.push(childRow.name);
        }
    })
  }
});

console.log(selectedElements);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a line before your lodash _.filter

```
array = _.flatten(array.map(x => [x].concat(x.childs)))
```

so it will take the `childs`.

Answer (score 0):

A classic recursive solution with arrow functions

```
var result = [];
var recursiveSearch = arr => {
  if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
    arr.forEach(x => {
    if (x.selected === true) result.push(x.name);
    if (Array.isArray(x.childs)) recursiveSearch(x.childs);
    });
  }
}
recursiveSearch(data);
console.log (result);
```